# Remaping labels with ASM4

Tags: java, local-variables, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation

I'm using [ASM4](http://asm.ow2.org/) for some Java bytecode manipulation. I want to copy some code from one method to another one. The latter has some additional code and because of that every `LabelNode` from the first method must be remapped.

The problem arise when local variables needs to be inserted. I followed this pattern: get the local variables from first method, create a copy of it with index and start label and ending label nodes modified. The visitor used to get the local variable has this form:

```
public void visitLocalVariable(String name, String desc, String signature, Label start, Label end, int index)
```

and the code that should insert a new local variable look like this:

```
localVariableList.add(new LocalVariableNode((String name, String desc, String signature, LabelNode start, LabelNode end, int index)))
```

Problem is, the `info` field from `Label` object is null, therefore I can't get a reference of the old `LabelNode` so that I could remap with my new label nodes.

I also tried to get the offset from the code with `label.getOffset()` and then remap the offset to a list of offsets associated with my new list of `LabelNode` but I get an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Label offset position has not been resolved yet
at org.objectweb.asm.Label.getOffset(Unknown Source)
```

If any of you has an idea of how could I get the corresponding `LabelNode` from a `Label` would be much appreciated. 
Or maybe there's  a better approach on copying the code from one method to another one and resolving the issue with labels, lablenode's and localvariables.

Most of the time I use the tree API because of it's simplicity.

Thank for you help.

Comment: If you are copying one `InsnList` to another, you can use `resetLabels()` to have the label offsets and positions realign correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an example of similar transformation in "Inline Method" section of my [AOSD'07 paper](http://asm.ow2.org/current/asm-transformations.pdf).